# How to unshadow symbol in a Common Lisp

Tags: common-lisp

I've shadowed 'and symbol doing some experiments:

```
MATCHERS> (package-shadowing-symbols *package*)
(AND)
```

Neither `(setf (package-shadowing-symbols *package*) nil)` nor Slime don't work.

Comment: Uninterning the symbols should work.

Answer (score 5):

Alas, there is no non-destructive way to solve your problem: "shadowing" means that you have "something" (`temp-pack::and`) between the "light source" (`cl:and`) and the spot you are looking at (string `"AND"` below):

```
(let ((*package* (find-package '#:temp-pack)))
  (read-from-string "AND"))
=> TEMP-PACK::AND, 3
```

The only way out is to remove the obstacle blocking the light.

The modified example from [`shadow`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_shadow.htm)
should be instructive:

```
(package-shadowing-symbols (make-package '#:temp-pack))
=> NIL
(find-symbol "AND" '#:temp-pack)
=> AND, :INHERITED
(shadow "AND" '#:temp-pack)
=> T
(find-symbol "AND" '#:temp-pack)
=> TEMP-PACK::AND, :INTERNAL
(package-shadowing-symbols '#:temp-pack)
=> (TEMP-PACK::AND)
(find-all-symbols "AND")
=> (:AND AND TEMP-PACK::AND)
(unintern 'temp-pack::and '#:temp-pack)
=> T
(find-all-symbols "AND")
=> (:AND AND)
(package-shadowing-symbols '#:temp-pack)
=> NIL
```

You have to actually [`unintern`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_uninte.htm) `AND` from `TEMP-PACK` because as long as it is interned there, it will be shadowing [`CL:AND`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/a_and.htm).

Moreover, the trick of saving the symbol does *not* work:

```
(shadow "AND" '#:temp-pack)
=> T
(defparameter temp-pack-and 'temp-pack::and)
=> TEMP-PACK-AND
(unintern 'temp-pack::and '#:temp-pack)
=> T
(shadow "AND" '#:temp-pack)
=> T
temp-pack-and
=> #:AND
(eq temp-pack-and 'temp-pack::and)
=> NIL
```

This is because [`intern`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_intern.htm) creates a *new* symbol:

> If a symbol whose name is the same as string is already accessible in package, it is returned. If no such symbol is accessible in package, a new symbol with the given name is created and entered into package as an internal symbol